# more than one device/emulator react native Error in react native start

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

I start my Genymotion then i do `npm start` on my **react native** project via VS Code . i got this message:

```
>Press a to open android device or Emulator
>Press q to display QrCode
 .
 .
```

so i pressed a but i got this error:

> Error running adb: more than one device/emulator

how can i solve this? i tried `adb devices` to see my devices and i saw this list:

```
emulator-5562 host
emulator-5560 host
emulator-5558 host
192.168.X.X device
```

my OS is windows 10. i couldn't even start my react native `hellow-world` still

***Edit:*** i turned of my system and in next day every thing worked on . why? i checked devices again by this command:  `adb devices` this time the list includes just one device : `192.168.X.X device` so we have to have only one device as emulator but!! how can i kill all devices just one in adb?

Comment: @mjsameri no i don't use it

Comment: @mjsameri No i didn't hear about them ...no

Comment: @mjsameri yes now when it worked on i knew its working with Expo..

Answer (score 17):

This happened to me although I had just one Genymotion emulator running. The problem was I was charging my phone with my laptop, and I had USB debugging enabled. Disabling USB debugging in my phone fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes...This is exactly what solved the problem...either you turn off USB debugging or disconnect the usb cable connected to your mac

Comment: No need at all to kill your adb.exe process fellas. This one is the correct answer. +1 for correct info 

Answer (score 9):

Open your *task manager* and in the background processes finalize the adb process.

Answer (score 2):

Stop all open devices,emulators. 
Go to Android Studio > Tools > AVD manager > and click the right most drop-down > click Stop. Stop them all devices. 
$ adb devices
should only show one device attached. (specially when running on a real device and not a simulator)
Close the AVD manager too. 
almost no setup needed.

Answer (score 1):

Same error with Expo XDE for React Native apps.
Trying to deploy on test device while charging phone.
Solution: disabled `debug usb` on second phone solved the problem (as error log suggested)

Comment: @It works for me. my physical device is connected to my laptop and after disconnect my physical device everything works well.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody stumbles upon this question.. you can also use 
 
`react-native run-android --deviceId=<deviceId where you want to run your app>`

Comment: You can know the Id by running `adb devices`. Right?

Comment: @mayid absolutely

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure what to do, then:

1. Disconnect any phone which might be connected to your computer.
2. Close all the Apps and restart your computer.
3. After restart open just one emulator from android studio.  If running on real device, connect just one device (and close the emulator).

The error is showing because bundler is detecting more than one device/emulator which are connected via ADB.

** Scan QR Code to run your app on multiple devices at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Open TaskManager search for adb.exe and close it go back to your console press a again and it will work

[image: exp]

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble stopping individual emulators, `adb kill-server` quite reliably stops all emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issues were occurring for me using Flutter. I used both USB and `adb connect IP:Port` to connect my device. As a result, the same devices are connected in two ways. My issue was resolved when I performed `adb kill-server`, unplugged the device from the USB, and then connected solely over IP. Hope it helps.